# Saving HTML5 canvas data

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm creating a whiteboard application using ASP.NET/JavaScript. HTML5 canvas is my current tool for developing whiteboard features (drawing, text, image, shape ...). How can I save my scene so that I can load it later (and continue drawing)? I've seen a function for saving PNG image of the canvas, is it the only way of saving canvas data? or is there another way that enables me to save canvas data along their semantics, for instance can I save lines, shapes, texts and images drawing on the canvas? what are my options?

Comment: Ram Kulkarni did a post describing how to serialize & replay canvas sketchings by recording the drag-points to JSON.  You can start with Ram's code that serializes points and extend it to serialize any context commands you desire: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/deserializing-recordings-in-recordable-html5-canvas/

Comment: save data using ajax from html in javascirpt

Comment: Related: [Draw image on canvas from image data stored in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591955/draw-image-on-canvas-from-image-data-stored-in-database/77592106#77592106)

Answer (score 2):

A canvas is a rasterised output of the instructions given to it, purely pixel data is stored. If you need to know the steps taken to get there you will need to log them in the javascript you are using to create it in the first place. Otherwise, if it was relatively simple, you could draw each element to stacked / offscreen canvases and export these separately. Obviously this could get expensive depending on the amount you need to do.

There are things like [this](http://www.yankov.us/canvasundo/) that 'undo' canvas operations but essentially it's just storing an array of lines and redrawing them all from scratch every time.  If you click undo it removes a line from the array, otherwise it adds one.  To do what you desire you would need to store an array of operations to be drawn like this from a completely black canvas.